# HTML5: play on speakers stream from microphone on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, linux, html, ubuntu, firefox

I am learning html5 and want to try to play on speakers what I say on microphone. So I wrote the following js code:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

var aCtx;
var analyser;
var microphone;
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia(
        {audio: true}, 
        function(stream) {
            aCtx = new AudioContext();
            analyser = aCtx.createAnalyser();
            microphone = aCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
            microphone.connect(analyser);
            var destination=aCtx.destination;
            analyser.connect(destination);
        },
        function(){ console.log("Error 003.")}
     );
}
```

I test it on firefox 47 and ubuntu 14. I see the panel to share my microphone, I select share and nothing  I hear nothing. How to fix it?

**EDIT:**
However, it works on firefox 47 in windows7. But in ubuntu I have all drivers installed and I use skype, youtube etc everything works except this js script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem. There are some `additional` settings:CubebUtils
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It works for me on both firefox and chrome (I'm on a Macbook Pro OSX 10.11)

https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/g88v7p8c/

Note it doesn't run on stackoverflow because using the mic requires HTTPS (at least on Chrome, didn't check firefox). If the page is not HTTPS then I get

> `getUserMedia()` no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See httpsgoo.gl/rStTGz for more details.`

stupid stackoverflow won't let me post the actual message from chrome because stackoverflow bans goo.gl

Comment: So, you speak and hear what you say on speakers?

Comment: [Works for me in Ubuntu as well](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3lezSyO5UM). I tried both Chrome and Firefox. Sorry, I don't know what else to suggest

Comment: Seems something either with driver or hardware - it sometimes works sometimes not. The same js code.

Comment: Thank you your help. I found out the problem. See my answer