# Play Mic audio back continuously

Tags: javascript, dom, audio, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I see a lot of questions for how to record audio then stop recording, then play audio or save it to a file, but none of this is what I want.

tl;dr Here's my question in a nutshell: "How can I immediately play audio recorded from the user's microphone?" That is, I *don't* want to save a recording and play it when the user hits a "Play" button, I *don't* want to save a recording to a file on the user's computer and I *don't* want to use WebRTC to stream audio anywhere. I just want to talk into my microphone and hear my voice come out the speakers.

All I'm trying to do is make a very simple "echo" page that just immediately plays back audio recorded from the mic. I started using a `mediaRecorder` object, but that wasn't working and from what I can tell that's meant for recording full audio files, so I switched to an `AudioContext`-based approach.
A very simple page would just look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mcve.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="speaker" volume="1.0"></audio>
</body>
```

and the script looks like this:

```
if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
    var constrains = {audio: true};

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constrains).then(
        function (stream) {
            var context = new AudioContext();
            var source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
            var proc = context.createScriptProcessor(2048, 2, 2);

            source.connect(proc);

            proc.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
                console.log("audio data collected");
                let audioData = new Blob(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0), {type: 'audio/ogg' } )
                    || new Blob(new Float32Array(2048), {type: 'audio/ogg'});

                var speaker = document.getElementById('speaker');

                let url = URL.createObjectURL(audioData);
                speaker.src = url;
                speaker.load();
                speaker.play().then(
                    () => { console.log("Playback success!"); }, 
                    (error) => { console.log("Playback failure... ", error); }
                );
            };
        }
    ).catch( (error) => {
        console.error("couldn't get user media.");
    });
}
```

It can record non-trivial audio data (i.e. not every collection winds up as a `Blob` made from the `new Float32Array(2048)` call), but it can't play it back. It never hits the "could not get user media" catch, but it always hits the "Playback Failure..." catch. The error prints like this:

```
DOMException [NotSupportedError: "The media resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not suitable."
code: 9
nsresult: 0x806e0003]
```

Additionally, the message `Media resource blob:null/<long uuid> could not be decoded.` is printed to the console repeatedly.

There are two things that could be going on here, near as I can tell (maybe both):

1. I'm not encoding the audio. I'm not sure if this is a problem, since I thought that data collected from the mic came with 'ogg' encoding automagically, and I've tried leaving the `type` property of my `Blob`s blank to no avail. If this is what's wrong, I don't know how to encode a chunk of audio given to me by the `audioprocess` event, and that's what I need to know.
2. An `<audio>` element is fundamentally incapable of playing audio fragments, even if properly encoded. Maybe by not having a full file, there's some missing or extraneous metadata that violates encoding standards and is preventing the browser from understanding me. If this is the case, maybe I need a different element, or even an entirely scripted solution. Or perhaps I'm supposed to construct a file-like object in-place for each chunk of audio data?

I've built this code on examples from MDN and SO answers, and I should mention I've tested my mic at [this example demo](https://mdn.github.io/web-dictaphone/) and it appears to work perfectly.

The ultimate goal here is to stream this audio through a websocket to a server and relay it to other users. I *DON'T* want to use WebRTC if at all possible, because I don't want to limit myself to only web clients - once it's working okay, I'll make a desktop client as well.

Comment: Your question is not very clear.

Comment: How so? What could I do to make it more clear?

Comment: Have a look at the [`DelayNode`](https://devdocs.io/dom/delaynode).

Comment: @K3N I'm not sure how that would help, since I'm not trying to make a looping audio source, and introducing a manual delay seems like a bad idea for when I switch to the server/relay system.

Comment: I believe @anoneemus wants the audio to playback while recording — in other words, hear the input as its being recorded. Anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Check example https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/g88v7p8c/ from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38280110/351900

Required to be run from HTTPS

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
    
var aCtx;
var analyser;
var microphone;
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.getUserMedia(
    {audio: true}, 
    function(stream) {
      aCtx = new AudioContext();
      microphone = aCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
      var destination=aCtx.destination;
      microphone.connect(destination);
    },
    function(){ console.log("Error 003.")}
  );
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. For test purposes you can run it on localhost or even using chrome specific insecure-origin-as-secure https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/85564289/how-to-enable-the-microphone-in-an-insecure-website?hl=en